# OracleDataReader HasRows throws Invalid Number Exception

Tags: c#, oracle

I have the following code:

```
int count = 0;
OracleDataReader dr;
parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("Username", UserName);

query = "Select KEY from TABLE1 where USERID=:Username AND KEY IN(";

foreach (string Location in Locations)
{
    query = query + ":Loc" + count.ToString() + ",";

    parameters.Add("Loc" + count.ToString(), Location);

    count++;
}
query=query.TrimEnd(',');
query = query + ")";

dr=objConexion.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters, objConexion.OracleCnn);


public OracleDataReader ExecuteQuery(String query, Dictionary<string,string> Parameters, OracleConnection oracleCnn)
{
    OracleDataReader OracleDr;
    OracleCommand OracleCmd;
    try
    {


        OracleCmd = oracleCnn.CreateCommand();
        OracleCmd.CommandText = query;


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Parameters)
        {

            OracleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

        }

        OracleCmd.Prepare();
        OracleDr = OracleCmd.ExecuteReader();

    }
    catch
    {
        OracleDr = null;
    }

    return OracleDr;
}
```

For some reason the code works fine sometimes and others it doesn´t, After debugging I noticed that when it doesn´t work, the Datareader has an exception on its "HasRows" method, specifically an Invalid Number Exception. I have tried running the resulting query directly on the DBMS and it executes perfectly, does anyone know why this exception is happening? what am I missing?.

Comment: Could you provide the exception? Or is it just InvalidNumber? - InvalidNumber is thrown in oracle when conversion of string to number fails. Please provide the table description with column types.

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number, although when looking at it on debug, it only says: HasRows 'dr.HasRows' generated an exception 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException'. They Key column which I am selecting is an INTEGER and the UserID is a varchar2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to find issue:

```
 OracleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, int.Parse(kvp.Value));
```

I think, you passing some "bad integer" in one of the locations
See this [sql error "ORA-01722: invalid number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549029/sql-error-ora-01722-invalid-number)

And please, remove

```
OracleCmd.Prepare();
```

Another thing, why do you pass connection to

```
public OracleDataReader ExecuteQuery(String query, 
                                     Dictionary<string,string> Parameters, 
                                     OracleConnection oracleCnn)
```

Pass a connection string and open connection before execution. Use appropriate `CommandBehavior`

**MSDN**: [CommandBehavior.CloseConnection]When the command is executed, the associated Connection object is closed when the associated DataReader object is closed.

Comment: The issue is not on the parameters as the query works sometimes, I tried it anyways and got the same result, (also tried removing the Prepare statement. The connection is being passed because I have a custom connection object that contains different connection strings (for different environments) and it opens the appropriate connection based on a paramter, the connection is being opened and closed properly in the code before and after the snippet I posted. It might not be the best way, but this is what I have to work with.

Comment: @user3255067 At which line of code the error occurs?

Comment: Managed to find the problem, it was actually outside the snippet I posted, it was a logic error, that was sending strings sometimes instead of integers as parameters as you suggested, thanks.