# Query who generates insert statements : invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute a query who generates inserts statements, like that :

```
select 
  'insert into MYTABLE (
    ID, 
    COLUMN_A, 
    COLUMN_B)
  values (' + 
    ID + ',' +
    COLUMN_A + ',' +
    COLUMN_B  
as INSERTGENERATOR from MYTABLE;
```

But I have this error :

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Why ?
I tried with `||` instead of `+`, and with `to_char`, but it but it does not change.

Comment: maybe u miss the end ')' and ';' ? or just they are not shown on the example ?

Comment: @Melon Yes it's for the example, sorry :x

Comment: this could help ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549029/sql-error-ora-01722-invalid-number

Comment: Just use the simple string literal technique, q'[]', see my demonstration in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put end of lines within quotes. And `||` is used to concatenate.

```
select 
  'insert into MYTABLE (ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B) values (' ||
    ID || ',' ||
    COLUMN_A || ',' ||
    COLUMN_B || ');'
as INSERTGENERATOR from MYTABLE;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
SELECT
  'INSERT INTO MYTABLE 
  (ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
   VALUES (' || 
    ID || ',' ||
    COLUMN_A || ','||
    COLUMN_B || ');'
AS INSERTGENERATOR 
FROM MYTABLE;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be2cc/4)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the pain while concatenating string literals using pipes "||" etc. Just use the latest string literal feature **`q'[]'`**.

```
SQL> SELECT q'[insert into MYTABLE (
  2  ID,
  3  COLUMN_A,
  4  COLUMN_B)
  5  values ('ID', 'COLUMN_A','COLUMN_B')]'
  6  AS INSERTGENERATOR
  7  FROM DUAL
  8  /

INSERTGENERATOR
-------------------------------------------
insert into MYTABLE (
ID,
COLUMN_A,
COLUMN_B)
values ('ID', 'COLUMN_A','COLUMN_B')

SQL>
```

Neat, isn't it?

Comment: Surely `ID`, `COLUMN_A` and `COLUMN_B` should be the values from `MYTABLE`, not those literals? In which case they'd have to be concatenated? (Though I like the quoted syntax in general; just not sure it quite works here...)

Comment: I agree. Just realized those are column names and not literals. In that case, column names has to be concatenated. Perhaps, OP would find the new string literal technique quite handy at times when he would like to build complex dynamic strings :-) By the way, thanks for pointing it out.