# Passing floats to oracle DB from PHP (PDO) raises ORA-01722 only if using bindParam

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Here is a float, declared in PHP:

```
$floatValue = 6.66;
```

Saving it to an Oracle database like this works fine:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO fooTable (numValue) VALUES($floatValue)");
$statement->execute();
//All good!
```

However, if I use bindParam, error ORA-01722 is raised:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO fooTable (numValue) VALUES(?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $floatValue);
$statement->execute();
//ORA-01722 raised
```

This only happens with floats, ints are fine.

I tried changing the decimal separator in my OS, no problem there.

So what's happening here?

Why only floats?

Is there an alternative to bindParam specificaly for Floats..?

Comment: what happens when you add `PDO::PARAM_INT` or `PDO::PARAM_STR` as an additional argument? also checking for errors http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php should there be anything else that may have not been caught.

Comment: Have a look at this entire post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549029/sql-error-ora-01722-invalid-number to see if there's anything in there that may be relevant to be tried. Also https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php

Comment: NUMBER(2,5) is probably wrong, it should be NUMBER(5,2). But NUMBER should work. ORA-01722 is raised when Oracle tries to convert a STRING to a NUMBER; I don't know how the passing of numbers from PHP to Oracle works, is it always through string representation of numbers? If so, see if there is a mismatch in the character used as the decimal separator, between PHP and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys!
I've narrowed the problem down and edited the question consequently; the problem seems to come from the use of bindParam.

Answer (score 1):

What was working for me is setting the ORACLE decimal separator (for the session) before the insert statement:

```
$stmt = $connection->exec( "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. '");
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$floatValue = 6.66;
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO fooTable (numValue) VALUES(?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $floatValue);
$statement->execute();

$s = $connection->prepare('select * from fooTable');
$s->execute();
while ($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

gives the expected output:

```
array(1) {
  ["NUMVALUE"]=>
  string(4) "6.66"
}
```

This is expected because the fetch converts to string.  In SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> desc fooTable
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NUMVALUE                                           NUMBER

SQL> select * from fooTable;

  NUMVALUE
----------
      6.66
```