# Invalid number in Oracle SQL Case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hi im habing trouble with a SQL case, the problem is im trying to run a case with 7 different columns, the columns can have different kinds of data (string,date,number) depending on an id.

This means that under some id's the rows in a column will be string while under other ids the rows in a column will be number.

I realise this isn't a conventional use of astructured database, but this specific table serve a specific purpose where this approach was deemed usefull in the past.

The case is supposed to only select a "then" when the column does have a number. However when i run it i get a invalid number ORA-01722. because one of the, rows will hold a string og date.

I realise its properly because oracle asses the sql before executing, and doesnt execute sequential, therefore giving errors on these column even though it wouldn actually have to calculate on the column under a given ID.

The code im trying to execute is the following, The hardcoded 1 and 2 before 'then' will change depending on ctrl_id (the unique id) and it will be the one securing that we only look and a list_val  column/row with a number

```
WITH sampledata1 AS
 (SELECT '1' ctrl_id, '23' list_val1, 'Textfield' list_val2
    FROM dual),
sampledata2 AS
 (SELECT '2' ctrl_id, 'Textfield' list_val1, '45' list_val2
    FROM dual),
sampledata3 AS
 (SELECT *
    FROM sampledata1
  UNION
  SELECT *
    FROM sampledata2)
SELECT CASE
          WHEN ctrl_id = 1 THEN
           AVG(list_val1)
           over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
          WHEN ctrl_id = 2 THEN
           AVG(list_val2)
           over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
        END AS avg_val
  FROM sampledata3 qd
```

Any suggestions to how i can make this work. either a workaround or a different approach ?

Thx in advance.

--------- Solution below

I used some of the suggestions and solutions posted below and got this code samble working. I will try and implement it with the system. Thx for the help everyone you saved me alot of headache.

```html
 WITH sampledata1
     AS (SELECT '1' ctrl_id, '23' list_val1, 'Textfield' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata2
     AS (SELECT '2' ctrl_id, 'Textfield' list_val1, '45' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata3
     AS (SELECT * FROM sampledata1
         UNION
         SELECT * FROM sampledata2)
 select ctrl_id,
 avg(CASE WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(list_val1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')) is null 
 then list_val1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC) list_val1,
    avg(CASE WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(list_val2, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')) is null 
 then list_val2 else null end) over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC) list_val2
       
            from   sampledata3 qd
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including DDL statements for your tables (especially since you have multiple data types) and some sample data that illustrates the problem and your expected output for that sample data. Also, please include a complete query as you only have a snippet and the `de` alias appears to be undefined so it is impossible to replicate your problem.

Comment: Im sorry ill add a sample code.

Comment: I have replaced the code with a sample code which has exactly the same problem, and gives the same error, its runable on any oracle db. And maybe others if the 'Dual' function exists.

Comment: @EclecticFish Aggregate function like `AVG` does not work with `VARCHAR` data type, `NUMBER` or `INTEGER` is a must when such functions are being used.

Comment: @user75ponic Yeah but the DBMS will convert the columns with numbers like 23 and 45 to number from varchar. and it will work. The problem is that the entire column isn't just numbers list_val1 and list_val2 also have a row with a varchar with letters 'Textfield'.

However the case should ensure that it wont try to calculate avg on these columns on thouse rows. But the way SQL functions does that this approach doesn't work. (like it would in JAVA or C# where it runs sequential)

Comment: @EclecticFish Numerics stored in VARCHAR data type is possible to cast to NUMBER, however, the reverse is not certainly impossible. This is precisely the error `invalid number ORA-01722`

Comment: @EclecticFish One option is having a check whether the row returned is numeric or non-numeric.

Comment: @user75ponic that might be a solution. Do you have any ideas to how i could check if the row returned is numeric ? Because as the setup (im working on a legacy system) is today, i wont be able to remove the letters(textfields) since they have a function in other controls. Again i know this isn't best praticse and all, so im looking for a workaround :)

Comment: @EclecticFish I have updated my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The [aggregate function](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32693.html) like `AVG` does not work with `VARCHAR` data type, `NUMBER` or `INTEGER` is a must when such functions are being used.

I have modified the query to have number instead of a string,

```
WITH sampledata1
     AS (SELECT '1' ctrl_id, '23' list_val1, '43' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata2
     AS (SELECT '2' ctrl_id, '34' list_val1, '45' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata3
     AS (SELECT * FROM sampledata1
         UNION
         SELECT * FROM sampledata2)
SELECT CASE
          WHEN ctrl_id = 1
          THEN
             AVG (list_val1)
                OVER (PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
          WHEN ctrl_id = 2
          THEN
             AVG (list_val2)
                OVER (PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
       END
          AS avg_val
  FROM sampledata3 qd
```

The output is

```
  AVG_VAL
----------
        23
        45
```

**Edit 1**

Perhaps you can do something like the below to first ascertain row return NUMERIC or NON-NUMERIC.

Change as per your requirements.

```
WITH sampledata1
     AS (SELECT '1' ctrl_id, '23' list_val1, 'Textfield' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata2
     AS (SELECT '2' ctrl_id, 'Textfield' list_val1, '45' list_val2 FROM DUAL),
     sampledata3
     AS (SELECT * FROM sampledata1
         UNION
         SELECT * FROM sampledata2),
     sampledata4
     AS (SELECT LENGTH (TRIM (TRANSLATE (ctrl_id, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))
                   ctrl_id,
                LENGTH (TRIM (TRANSLATE (list_val1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))
                   list_val1,
                LENGTH (TRIM (TRANSLATE (list_val2, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))
                   list_val2
           FROM sampledata3 qd                   --           group by ctrl_id
                              )
(  SELECT CASE WHEN ctrl_id IS NULL THEN AVG (ctrl_id) ELSE 0 END ctrl_id,
          CASE WHEN list_val1 IS NULL THEN AVG (list_val1) ELSE 0 END list_val1,
          CASE WHEN list_val2 IS NULL THEN AVG (list_val2) ELSE 0 END list_val2
     FROM sampledata4
 GROUP BY ctrl_id, list_val1, list_val2)
```

Comment: This version nearly worked, it did however only show the length of the textfield (9), however this combined with some of the other answers solved my problem. Thx you very much for your time :). I will add the solution to my original question.

Comment: @EclecticFish Glad to know that the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to filtered out values with non-numeric symbols with something like

```
AVG(CASE WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(list_val1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')) is null then list_val1 else null end) OVER (...)
```

NB! Unfortunately strings like '+12-.3' also will be recognized as a numeric and in this case you will get same ora-01722

Comment: Used this in corroboration with an other answer and got the code working. Thx for the answer much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using that Analytic function. For your basic problem this would work:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE
              WHEN ctrl_id = 1 THEN list_val1
              WHEN ctrl_id = 2 THEN list_val2
            END) AS avg_val
FROM sampledata3 qd
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get Average sum of `list_val1`, However `list_val1` from `sampledata2` query returns VARCHAR value.

You shouldn't use AVG on non-numeric values.

```
WITH sampledata1 AS
 (SELECT '1' ctrl_id, '23' list_val1, '10' list_val2
    FROM dual),
sampledata2 AS
 (SELECT '2' ctrl_id, '45' list_vall, '90' list_val2
    FROM dual),
sampledata3 AS
 (SELECT *
    FROM sampledata1
  UNION
  SELECT *
    FROM sampledata2)
SELECT CASE
          WHEN ctrl_id = 1 THEN
           AVG(list_val1)
           over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
          WHEN ctrl_id = 2 THEN
           AVG(list_val2)
           over(PARTITION BY qd.ctrl_id ORDER BY qd.ctrl_id ASC)
        END AS avg_val
  FROM sampledata3 qd
```