# how to use slash '/' in Id_user field of type string and insert it into database using controller in laravel 8?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is the function I use to insert a new user into the database:

```php
public function store_user(Request $request){
    $user = new User();      

    $user->id_user = "999/11"; // this is the problem      

    $user->name= $request->input('user_name');
    $user->last_name= $request->input('last_name');
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/users');
}
```

Every time I got this error

> Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number Position : 100 Statement : insert into "users" ("ID_USER", "UPDATED_AT", "CREATED_AT") values (:p0, :p1, :p2) returning "ID_USER" into :p3 Bindings : [999/11,2020-10-27 10:18:03,2020-10-27 10:18:03,0]

Comment: what is datatype of `id_user ` column in database ? it should not be integer

Comment: VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)

Comment: then why it is showing `invalid number`  i think you need to try with normal int is it working or not

Comment: The database is pre-existing, I can't change anything. id_user is varchar(8byte). id_user is composed of three things = number(represent departement)  + / + (num of user).

Comment: can you please confirm if this is the full error stack trace?

Comment: Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception
Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number Position : 100
 Statement : insert into "users" ("ID_USER", "UPDATED_AT", "CREATED_AT") values (:p0, :p1, :p2) returning "ID_USER" into :p3
 Bindings : [999/11,2020-10-27 10:18:03,2020-10-27 10:18:03,0]

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549029/sql-error-ora-01722-invalid-number

Comment: can you please try with `$user->id_user = "string99";` and share if it is working or not?

Comment: No. it does not work: Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception
Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number
 Position : 100 Statement : insert into "UTIL_PARQUET" ("ID_USER", "UPDATED_AT", "CREATED_AT") values (:p0, :p1, :p2) returning "ID_USER" into :p3
 Bindings : [/999/11,2020-10-27 11:09:50,2020-10-27 11:09:50,0]

Comment: Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception
Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number
 Position : 100 Statement : insert into "UTIL_PARQUET" ("ID_USER", "UPDATED_AT", "CREATED_AT") values (:p0, :p1, :p2) returning "ID_USER" into :p3
 Bindings : [string99,2020-10-27 11:11:38,2020-10-27 11:11:38,0]

Answer (score 0):

whats is **(`id_user`)** type in database ?

If it is **int**, you can not enter. You must change its type to **string**

Comment: VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)

Comment: I have no idea if it is varchar